# How to add all the values of Data Class field into another list

Tags: kotlin

I am downloading a JSON Object and storing it in a data class. I am able to download the data and successfully and store it in the data class. I want to store all the values inside the `option` field (which is an array) in the JSON object into a separate `ArrayList`.

> JsonSchema

```
    {8 items
    "area":"sat"
    "author":"twinword inc."
    "email":"help@twinword.com"
    "level":3
    "quizlist":[10 items
    0:{3 items
    "correct":2
    "option":[2 items
    0:"jury"
    1:"assess"
    ]
    "quiz":[3 items
    0:"value"
    1:"estimate"
    2:"evaluate"
    ]
    }
    1:{...}3 items
    2:{...}3 items
    3:{...}3 items
    4:{...}3 items
    5:{...}3 items
    6:{...}3 items
    7:{...}3 items
    8:{...}3 items
    9:{...}3 items
    ]
    "result_code":"200"
    "result_msg":"Success"
    "version":"4.0.0"
}
```

> DataClasses

```
data class Game2Model(@SerializedName("area") var area : String,
                      @SerializedName("level") var level : Int,
                      @SerializedName("quizlist") var quizlist : List<QuizData>,
                      @SerializedName("version") var version : String,
                      @SerializedName("author") var author : String,
                      @SerializedName("email") var email : String,
                      @SerializedName("result_code") var resultCode : String,
                      @SerializedName("result_msg") var resultMsg : String ){}




data class QuizData(  @SerializedName("quiz") var quiz : List<String>,
                      @SerializedName("option") var option : List<String>,
                      @SerializedName("correct") var correct : Int){}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you running into? You're more likely to get a helpful answer if you provide as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a list of all options in a single bigger list, you could do the following:

```
val allOptions = game2Model.quizlist.flatMap { q -> q.option }
```